# Getting "IllegalArguementException : Value for parameter 'id' was out of bounds" for poi apache library?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Getting "IllegalArguementException : Value for parameter 'id' was out of bounds" for poi(latest version) apache library.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value for parameter 'id' was out of bounds
at org.apache.poi.util.IdentifierManager.reserve(IdentifierManager.java:80)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun.<init>(XWPFRun.java:110)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph.buildRunsInOrderFromXml(XWPFParagraph.java:126)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph.<init>(XWPFParagraph.java:79)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:146)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:116)
```

The statement that is causing this exception is 
    `XWPFDocument doc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis1));`
where `fis1` is a simple `FileInputStream` Object.

Comment: What is the path of the file that you have passed in FileinputStream.

Comment: Where did the file come from? If you open it in Word does it give errors? Does open in word + save as produce a valid file?

Comment: @Sankumarsingh This is the path of the file `C:\Users\psehrawa\Documents\MyDocumentFiles\ayussing@alias.com\1641_TEST_27422_reportNew.docx`. Hope the file path is not an issue.

Comment: @Gagravarr The file origin i don't know but I don't have any issue in opening the file using Microsoft Word nor while save as the file.

Answer (score 4):

This apparently happens (at least) with docx files from LibreOffice.

Apart from the workaround of re-saving that document with Microsoft Office, a code fix is possible:

The problem is that the org.apache.poi.util.IdentifierManager is initialized for IDs starting at 1 in org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument; but docx files can contain (valid) IDs starting at 0.

After editing this constructor call to start from 0 instead of 1 and building local versions of the POI JARs, POI works correctly with documents that used to cause the above error message here.

Comment: FYI, this was fixed in POI and it should work starting with release 3.12

Comment: @centic I tried using 3.12-beta1, from the Maven repo, and I still experience the issue.

Comment: Can you please create a bug entry at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/ together with a sample file so we can analyse this in more detail.